# Does Jetpack Joyride automatically erase all your data if it's inactive for too long?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I'm thinking about giving up the game for Lent (in other words, 2/18 - 4/4, a period of 46 days), and I just want to know if there's a "timeout" period where the data is erased after a certain time without playing. I don't want to lose all my data when I return.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: ...why should it?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it is fine as long as you keep it on your device it will still be there. (I haven't played in about 6 months and just checked mine, and everything is just how I left it)